# Issues with radio buttons using Docusign Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I am having a few issues with Radio Buttons  when using the Docusign REST API V2.

I am using two radio groups, one is required and one is supposed to be optional. I will add the xml definitions at the end of this post. The buttons are appearing on the document, with the pre-selected values; however I am having two issues from here.

1. The second group is supposed to be optional, but it is appearing as required.
2. After selecting values and completing the document, the selections are not correct (see screenshots)

XML Tab definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<radioGroupTabs>
   <radioGroup>
      <groupName>RadioGroup1</groupName>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <radios>
         <radio>
            <anchorString>{RAD1}</anchorString>
            <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
            <selected>true</selected>
            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
         </radio>
         <radio>
            <anchorString>{RAD2}</anchorString>
            <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
            <selected>false</selected>
            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
         </radio>
      </radios>
   </radioGroup>
   <radioGroup>
      <groupName>RadioGroup2</groupName>
      <optional>true</optional>
      <radios>
         <radio>
            <anchorString>{RADA}</anchorString>
            <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
         </radio>
         <radio>
            <anchorString>{RADB}</anchorString>
            <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
         </radio>
      </radios>
   </radioGroup>
</radioGroupTabs>
```

[Image of selected radio values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUBz5.jpg)

[Image of document after selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q08cY.jpg)

Comment: Not seeing the `required` parameter listed for your radio buttons, you need to use that property to designate optional vs. required DocuSign tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To make a DocuSign tab or control required vs. optional, you will want to use the parameter required=true or required=false. Update your XML by removing the optional node and put required in there.
- You will want to assign a unique value to each **radio** in a given group, for example Yes. Add this and re-test.